# Reduce "raindrop" sound in python windsound.Beep

Tags: python, audio, beep

I was making a python program that uses `winsound.Beep(int, int)`, and I noticed that after it plays each beep it makes a loud annoying "raindrop" sound. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're experiencing is what's know as clicks in the audio world. They occur when an audio signal jumps rapidly in a value. They also occur when a signal suddenly stops but hasn't reached the zero crossing point. The diagram on this page here shows what's happening pretty well;

http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/oct06/articles/pcmusician_1006.htm

I've never used winsound.Beep, but looking at the documentation, it seems pretty high level. It's probably using a square wave and you hear the pop sound when the value is at 1 and then the signal stops. The speaker probably jumps back to its rest position and results in the raindrop sound you are hearing. You could, if you're really bothered, go into the code itself and edit it so that every time a sound is going be generated it is filtered through an amplitude envelope to get rid of these clicks, but this is way more time than it's worth. My advice is to change your method being used for generating your tones.